# In ruby, how to pass a class variable into a mixed-in module's dynamically created class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

SO...

I have a module...

```
module Foo
  class_methods do
    def bar(*fields)
      fields.each do |field|
        define_method("set_#{field}=") do |value|
          # nil check, other checks and validations
        end
    end
  end
end
```

...this module will be used in several of my models in my application, but for now I am trying to test it...

```
let(:entity_type) do
  class TestClass
    def initialize(value)
      @field_value = value
    end

    include Foo
    bar @field_value

    self
  end
end

let(:entity) { entity_type.new(:some_field) }
```

...however, when I put a break point in my tests and look at the entity's method, I only see "set_=" instead of "set_some_field=" and I have tried several variations on using symbols, class instance variables, etc. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says "dynamically created class method" but it looks like you're actually dynamically creating instance classes, ie, you could have multiple instances of TestClass, each with its own collection of set_x= methods. Is this what you want?

Assuming so, you can create the module:

```
module Foo
  def bar(*fields)
    fields.each do |field|
      define_method("set_#{field}=") do |value|
         # nil check, other checks and validations
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And create the class like so:

```
class TestClass
  extend Foo
  def initialize(value)
    @field_value = value
    TestClass.bar(@field_value)
  end
end
```

Such that: `t = TestClass.new("boop")` would give you instance class `t` with the method `set_boop=()`.

I should mention that if you create another instance, it will have any new methods you give it **as well as** all the previous methods from previous instances. This is because you're modifying the class definition with each instance.

If you don't want that functionality, you can use define_singleton_method and include the module rather than extending it, which makes bar an instance method designed to create other instance methods. Your class would instead look like this:

```
module Foo
  def bar(*fields)
    fields.each do |field|
      define_singleton_method("set_#{field}=") do |value|
        # nil check, other checks and validations
      end
    end
  end
end


class TestClass
  include Foo
  def initialize(value)
    @field_value = value
    bar(@field_value)
  end
end
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, let me know and i'll modify my answer.

Comment: Excellent answer.